# Ruby Iconv works with irb and ruby debugger but not in a unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, iconv

I'm running Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.  I've written a method that should take a string like this, `"École À la Découverte"` and output a file-system name like this `"ecole_a_la_decouverte"`:

```
(Iconv.new('US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'utf-8').iconv "École À la Découverte").downcase.split.join('_')
```

When I test this line in my code, the test always fails saying that `"cole_la_dcouverte"` is unequal to `"ecole_a_la_decouverte"`.  The odd thing is that if I insert a debugger line and use the debugger console the test passes.  As well, running this line manually in `irb` and `./script/console` seems to work.

Does anyone know what's going on and why this test is failing?  My only thought is that including the debugger or `irb` somehow adds more support for UTF-8 but I'm at a loss to figure out where to go next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it work in your rails console ? try in ./script/console

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rishav.  I tried running:

(Iconv.new('US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'utf-8').iconv "École À la Découverte").downcase.split.join('_')

in ./script/console and it produces:

"ecole_a_la_decouverte"

which is what I would expect so still no dice.  It was a good idea though!

Comment: +1 because I didn't know how to properly implement Iconv syntax and your question helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with the locale - the same which is also observed in php, where (sometimes?) iconv functions don't work if there is no locale set (whatever the locale).

See [a thread on this on ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/70827) where a low-level fix is suggested which allows you to set a locale using `setlocale()` in C.

Another suggestion is to install the [locale gem](http://www.yotabanana.com/hiki/ruby-locale.html).