# Make space to dash with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I've got a sinatra app where I plan to make a friedly-urls on the fly. I've got a function with a regexp that looks like this, but it won't turn 'spaces' into 'dashes', ' ' to '-'.

```
def self.make_slug(title)
  title.downcase.gsub(/ /, '-').gsub(/[^a-z0-9_]/, '').squeeze('-')
end
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Now I'm also trying to change åä into a and ö into o, my code looks like this but won't work, any ideas?

```
gsub(/[åä]/, 'a')
gsub(/[ö]/, 'o')
```

Comment: Yes it's from a Ruby app running the Sinatra framework.

Comment: The update is a new question, so: 1) look again for similar questions+answers, 2) look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046462 in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the language, you're first replacing " " with "-", and then replace everything but `a-z0-9_` (thus, also "-") with "". Include "-" in the list like `[^a-z0-9_-]`

Comment: Any idea how to make åäö into aao?

Comment: Yes, iconv is the magic word and google is your friend. Try `require 'iconv'` and `Iconv.conv("ASCII//TRANSLIT","UTF-8","åäö")`. This does work in irb but (apparently) fails in scripts when there is no locale set. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046462

Answer (score 8):

`title.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, '-').gsub(/[^a-z0-9_-]/, '').squeeze('-')`

This will take a given title (My &         Title5:) and:

* downcase it (my &   title5:)
* replace one or more white space characters with a - (my-&-title5:)
* replace non letters/number characters with nothing (my--title5)
* replace multiple occurrences of - with - (my-title5)

I hope this helps.